# Is 65 celsius temperature on a MacBook Pro 2017 okay?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

My 2017 MacBook Pro 15" gets really hot when it's connected to an external monitor. The temperature reaches 65 Celcius, and I am wondering if this is considered an okay temperature? If it is not what is the solution for such a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the **CPU** temperature, then yes **65°C** is okay.

The **2017 MacBook Pro 15"** model was available with three different **CPU's** with processor speeds of **2.8**, **2.9**, or **3.1 GHz**.

All three are rated to **100°C** for the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die.

See **T**<sub>**JUNCTION**</sub> in the **Package Specifications** section of the documentation for the **Intel Core i7** [**7700HQ**](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html), [**7820HQ**](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97496/intel-core-i7-7820hq-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html), and [**7920HQ**](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97462/intel-core-i7-7920hq-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html) Processors.

Comment: @haalshaikh, Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) - To thank someone for their answer, please considering marking it as the accepted answer and or up voting it.